# Custom edit page on a new project. Lightning Component, Lightning Design System or Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

It is so long that I wonder what is the best solution to the following problem.

I need to build a case custom edit page. Before the rise of "lightning" I would have started developing a custom visualforce page.

Now I'm looking for the right way to develope this page.

I would like to implement a page that follow all new Salesforce UX/UI standard and works both in SF Classic and LEX.

According to the last product enhancements and new features what is the best way to address a similar requirements (override standard page and functionalities)? What a developer should do in this casa?

Should I

1. build an old-style VF page
2. build a page using LDS framework and JS
3. Remote object or something like this build a lightning component and
   embedding it in a visualforce page

??

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a mix of 1 and 2, salesforce allows you to [check the user context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_useruitheme.htm). So you can use that on your page to know how to style it. Default on classic, LDS on LEX.

Lightning components are not quite ready for embedding purposes, working much better as standalone apps. I mean, if you're going to use a visualforce page to embed, why bother using the component at all?